# XamlReader - mapping multiple CLR namespaces to single XML namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I have a WPF project with an `AssemblyInfo.cs` that groups multiple CLR namespaces into a single XML namespace:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://foo.bar", "MyLibary.Controls")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://foo.bar", "MyLibary.Converters")]
```

In XAML this is used like so:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:fb="http://foo.bar">
    <fb:FooButton IsEnabled="{Binding Something, Converter={fb:FooConverter}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

This works great when the XAML is instantiated normally, but now I am now trying to dynamically load XAML files from my project using `XamlReader`.

The problem: I can't seem to map multiple CLR namespaces to a single XML namespace. It seems that the last definition added to the `XamlTypeMapper` is the only one that persists (e.g. it clobbers previous registrations):

```
var parserContext = new ParserContext();
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("fb", "http://foo.bar");

parserContext.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[] {"MyLibrary"});
parserContext.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("http://foo.bar", "MyLibrary.Converters", "MyLibrary");
parserContext.XamlTypeMapper.AddMappingProcessingInstruction("http://foo.bar", "MyLibrary.Controls", "MyLibrary");

...

var rootNode = XamlReader.Load(memeoryStream, parserContext) as FrameworkElement
```

The error message is:

```
'Cannot create unknown type '{http://foo.bar}MyConverter'.'
```

If all put all my code under a single common CLR namespace, everything works but unfortunately this is not option. Has anybody mapped multiple CLR namespaces to a single XML namespace for the purpose of loading XAML content dynamically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This [MSDN forum message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/wpf/thread/6390a403-96b4-426d-a89a-92f20d577b75) suggests that the assembly needs to be actually loaded for multiple CLR namespaces to work.

Comment: Thanks, did not see that thread. Removing all the calls to AddMappingProcessingInstruction and using Assembly.Load() before the XamlReader.Load() seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the solution is to manually load the assembly before invoking `XamlReader.Load` and removing the type mapper and context all together:

```
Assembly.Load("MyLibrary");
var rootNode = XamlReader.Load(memeoryStream) as FrameworkElement
```

I would have assumed since the `XamlTypeMapper` is initialized with a list of assemblies, that this class would be responsible for loading the assembly (and maybe it is) but the behaviour of `AddMappingProccessingInstruction` prevents this from working.